# Can we provide clickability to a TextWidget text in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-android

What I want is to be able to click on the words I specify and when I click it, it shows a callout with Easy Loading.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(t
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Risale-i Nur"),),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text("İhlas Risalesi - 1. Düstur", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineLarge),
          Text("""Eğer o razı olsa bütün dünya küsse ehemmiyeti yok. O razı olduktan ve kabul ettikten sonra, isterse ve hikmeti iktiza ederse sizler istemek talebinde olmadığınız halde, halklara da kabul ettirir, onları da razı eder. Onun için bu hizmette doğrudan doğruya yalnız Cenab-ı Hakk’ın rızasını esas maksat yapmak gerektir.""", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
class Strings{
  static const Map<String, String> words = {"iktiza":"mecburiyet", "ehemmiyeti":"kıymeti", "tesir":"etki"};
  /* 
    
    onPressed/onTap(){
    EasyLoading.showToast(words[KEY], dismissOnTap: true);
  } */
}
```

//I tried this but of course I can't write a widget in text

```
Widget mean(String key){
   return GestureDetector(
     child: Text(key),
     onTap: (){
       EasyLoading.showToast(words[key], dismissOnTap: true);
     }
   );
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "I can't write a widget in text"?

Answer (score 0):

You have few ways to do that.

You can use **RichText** and use **recognizer**

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart'; ...

RichText(
      text: TextSpan(text: 'Non touchable. ', children: [
        TextSpan(
          text: 'Tap here.',
          recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()..onTap = () => print('Tap Here onTap'),
        )
      ]),
    );
```

You can wrap your Text widget inside a **GestureDetector** widget

```
GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => function,
        child: Text(
          'Tap here.',
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

there is an widget named `TextButton`, you can check, demo and link is bellow,

```
TextButton(
    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
      textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
     ),
     onPressed:() {
        doSomthing();
      },
     child: const Text('Disabled'),
   )
```

[TextButton Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextButton-class.html)

Answer (score -1):

just wrap your text widget with `GestureDetector()` it will make it clickable.

```
  GestureDetector(onTap: () {
              //EasyLoading.showToast(words[KEY], dismissOnTap: true);
              }, child: Text("data")),
```